# Do JSON strings (digits only) need to be quoted?

Tags: json

Is it acceptable for JSON objects to omit quotes for strings that contain digits only?  For example, instead of {"name":"0"} should parsers also take care of {"name":0}?

We have an in-house parser that fails if string values are not quoted. However, we've tested the above with a 3rd party parser that has no problem parsing {"name":0} and returning value as a string - i.e. "0".

I'm not sure if we should insist that senders of JSON packets *always* quote the string values or should we modify the parser to take both quoted and non-quoted ones.

I'd appreciate any pointers to 'official' docs.

Comment: `0` means the number zero. `"0"` means the string zero. Either is valid JSON. A parser is non-conformant if it does not accept numbers. The official doc is json.org, which states that a value can be a string, a number, or several other things like true/false/null (**not** quoted).

Comment: http://www.json.org/

Comment: @torazaburo And now please post that as an answer.

Comment: @torazaburo Thanks for the comment.  However, this is not exactly what we are looking for. Let's say that a spec, e.g. Google's CJT format for cloud print, specifies that a given value is a string and then Chrome sends something that looks like a number (i.e. no quotes around the value) - should we reject it or should we be more lenient and take it as is?  We are familiar with json.org which is very clear about double qouted strings.  However, some parsers (e.g. .NET) have no problems dealing with non-quoted strings.  We're are just wondering if this is a common practice.

Comment: You are confusing what is valid JSON, and whether some JSON satisfies a particular schema. Either `0` or `"0"` is valid JSON as a value, and the parser should deal with it. If your schema or some API definition mandates or promises that some value should be a string then yes, it should be quoted, and if it's not, then a schema conformance checker should report that error. Sorry if I'm missing something here.

Comment: @torazaburo  I should've used 'schema' instead of 'spec' in my last comment. Our parser behaves exactly as you mentioned in your last comment: i.e. reports errors when string values are not quoted - as defined by a corresponding schema.  However, we've observed that other parsers (e.g. Microsoft .NET in Web API) are able to parse the non-quoted strings using the same input and schemas.   We've been dealing with some complaints that our parser is too strict.  Is it?

Answer (score 0):

the official [JSON spec](http://www.json.org/) says that numbers are unquoted.  if it's quoted, it's not a number, it's a string.  e.g. `"0"` is a string, not a number.